# Using jQuery Galleria how can one subscribe to a Youtube player ready event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, galleria

Galleria has a bunch of useful API functions (http://galleria.io/docs/api/events) but none of them appear to allow you to detect when a Youtube video player iFrame has successfully loaded.

The previous version of Galleria did not support video posters and so any YT videos in the gallery were automatically embedded into a slide when it was shown. Using the 'image' event (http://galleria.io/docs/api/events/#image) I could then detect if it was a video and hook into the YT player API.

Now that the video is initially a poster I cannot figure out how to detect when the player has loaded (after hitting the poster's play button) in order to manipulate it.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle with the basic gallery and a demo of the video posters: http://jsfiddle.net/9G5Gx/1/

Comment: Is Galleria loadfinish event something you are looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately loadfinish is triggered when the YT poster frame is complete, not when the YT iFrame has completed loading.